# Take text node of an element and manipulate it with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of elements that contain prices as such:

```
<em class="price">$859</em>
<em class="price">$159</em>
<em class="price">$850</em>
<em class="price">$350</em>
<em class="price">$560</em>
<em class="price">$200</em>
<em class="price">$250</em>
<em class="price">$900</em>
```

How would I be able to grab the values within the `<em>` tags and `console.log` them?

I know I can perform `[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` to grab the first one, and just change the value of the index in `childNodes` to grab any other one I wish.

Is there a way to take all the text node values at once without the use of a loop?

The bigger picture for why I would want to do this is I need to take each number in a `<em>` tag multiply it by a percentage, take that computed value and insert it into a newly generated element.

Is there a way to say (sudo code) "take all instances of `<em>` tags with the class `price`, multiply the text inside by `x`, and then insert newly computed values into `<em>` tags with the class called `new-price`"?

**EDIT**
This is how I'm using it currently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function setCheckPrice(){

var productPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('p-price');

console.log((productPrice)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);


}

  setCheckPrice();

});
```

This isn't logging anything in the console.

Using jQuery for when the document loads to apply the needed Javascript.

Comment: You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('price')`. Try that and post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a loop is probably best for what you want to do and to use jQuery as you already have it loaded. Try this:

```
function setCheckPrice() {
  $('.price').each(function(key, val) {
    var price = $(val).html().replace('$', '');
    var newPrice = parseInt(price) * 10;
    $(val).after('<em class="new-price">$' + newPrice + '</em>');
  });
}

setCheckPrice();
```

This will take each price, multiple it by 10 and insert it into a new `em` after the original one.

To target a single price, you'll just need to remove the each loop, for example:

```
function setCheckPrice() {
  var element = $('.price:nth-of-type(5)');
  var price = $(element).html().replace('$', '');
  var newPrice = parseInt(price) * 10;
  $(element).after('<em class="new-price">$' + newPrice + '</em>');
}

setCheckPrice();
```

You can target other elements by changing the 5.

Comment: This is a good answer, but for some reason it's throwing a `NaN` as the newly outputted price. What if I wanted this applied to just one element? Would I just remove the `.each` after grabbing the element?

Comment: That change did the trick for single items! One odd thing that I noticed is that for original numbers with four digits, the computed result ends in a `NaN`.

Comment: I updated the original function to use `parseInt(price)` as this should prevent the `NaN`, have you updated you code with that?